# java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter

Tags: android-listview

I got this error trying to get all items with specific object and store it to my Listview.

Following the codes:

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy");
            String selecdate = formatdate.format(date);

            if (eventDates.contains(selecdate)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < eventsList.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                    ListAdapter list = (ListAdapter) obj.get("eventtitle");
                    myList.setAdapter(list);
                }
            }
            else {
                myList.setAdapter(null);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter

This line is saying that your `obj.get("eventtitle");` is returning `String` as a value not a `ListAdapter`

As [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) says

> ```
> public abstract Object getItem (int position)
> ```
>
> Get the data item associated with the specified
>   position in the data set.

So might be your `dataSet` is of `String` rather than `ListAdapter`